# How to print on a different line after a print function within a loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to produce the pattern:

```
F
FE
FED
FEDC
FEDCB
FEDCBA
```

Using the following code:

```
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    for j in range(0,i+1):
        print(a[j], end='')
```

When executed I get the following pattern:

```
"FFEFEDFEDCFEDCBFEDCBA"
```

I know the `end=''` prints the next element next to the previous element. So how would I go about printing on a new line after I had already printed on the same line? Thanks.

Comment: replace `print(a[j], end='')` with `print(a[j])`. For one more line break you can use `print(a[j] + '\n')`

Comment: @BarunSharma then you get every character on its own line...

Comment: If you know that `end=''` makes it NOT print a newline, then obviously leaving out `end=''` makes it add a newline.

Comment: Add an *extra* `print`, outside the inner (`j`) loop but inside the outer (`i`) loop, with the default `end='\n'`. (You seem to have attracted no end of bad advice and answers here, sorry about that.)

Comment: @ChristopherBerry what is `a` ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oops...my mistake. Didn't read the question carefully.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing if `a` is `FEDCBA` , then what you need to do is to add a `print()` in the outer loop to print a newline. Example -

```
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    for j in range(0,i+1):
        print(a[j], end='')
    print()
```

---

But if `a` is really a string, you can simply do -

```
for i in range(1,len(a)+1):
    print(a[:i])
```

---

Demo -

```
>>> a = 'FEDCBA'
>>> for i in range(0,len(a)):
...     for j in range(0,i+1):
...         print(a[j], end='')
...     print()
...
F
FE
FED
FEDC
FEDCB
FEDCBA
>>> for i in range(1,len(a)+1):
...     print(a[:i])
...
F
FE
FED
FEDC
FEDCB
FEDCBA
```

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed.

Comment: Much better, thanks (although I'd be inclined to simplify to `range(len(a))` and make the slice `a[:i+1]`)

Answer (score -1):

```
a = ''
for i in range(0,10):
    a+= str(i)
    print a



#range(0,10) can be any series, such as str
```